# random alphanumeric string into hexadecimal in Python

Tags: python, string, random, alphanumeric

I'm trying to turn an alphanumeric string into a hexadecimal number.

The following code works as intended...

```
A = "f8g9dsf9s7ff7s9dfg98d9fg97s06s6df5"
B = int(A, 16)
```

When I try create the alphanumeric dynamically it breaks and doesn't get converted to hexadecimal number...

```
A = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=34))
B = int(A, 16)
```

Thanks for the help, extremely new to Python.

Comment: It's just a random keyboard smash to illustrate.

Comment: The code that "works as intended" would raise a `ValueError`

Comment: A hexadecimal number includes the characters 0-9 and a-f. Not all of a-z.

Comment: Please don't smash, because your first code does **not** work as intended.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "turn an alphanumeric string into a hexadecimal number"? Are you just trying to turn an arbitrary alphanumeric string into some arbitrary number?

Comment: ok so the random shouldn't use the full alphabet. thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.ascii_lowercase` is a string composed of the whole alphabet composed from 'a' to 'z' but only A..F are valid for hexadecimal which is base-16. Calling `int()` with non-A..F characters will raise a ValueError. Use string "abcdef" for the letters.

```python
import random
import string
A = ''.join(random.choices("abcdef"+ string.digits, k=34))
print(A)
B = int(A, 16)
print(B)
```

**Output:**

```
bf651615fd912a261eb4d5e752aec01f2e
65128298786024663864994496613621589614382
```